# append value in dictionary from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have dictionary with values and I would like to append values from list based on key of the list and dictionary

For example:

Here is my dictionary:

```
m_dict= {"Murder At Koh E Fiza" : "rot,r", "Subedar Joginder Singh" : "grn,4", "Blackmail" : "blau,9", "Rambo":"gelb,20"}
```

Here is my list:

```
m_list=['Murder At Koh E Fiza','tt','Subedar Joginder Singh','yy','Blackmail','uu','Rambo','zz']
```

Here is the final dictionary I want as an output

```
 m_dict= {"Murder At Koh E Fiza" : "rot,r,tt", "Subedar Joginder Singh" : "grn,4,yy", "Blackmail" : "blau,9,uu", "Rambo":"gelb,20,zz"}
```

Here is my code which I am trying:

```
for line in m_list:  
    m_dict.setdefault(m_dict, []).append(value)
```

But its not working for me. Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string formatting:

```
m_dict= {"Murder At Koh E Fiza" : "rot,r", "Subedar Joginder Singh" : "grn,4", "Blackmail" : "blau,9", "Rambo":"gelb,20"}
m_list=['Murder At Koh E Fiza','tt','Subedar Joginder Singh','yy','Blackmail','uu','Rambo','zz']
temp_dict = {m_list[i]:m_list[i+1] for i in range(0, len(m_list), 2)}
final_dict = {a:"{},{}".format(b, temp_dict[a]) for a, b in m_dict.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'Murder At Koh E Fiza': 'rot,r,tt', 'Subedar Joginder Singh': 'grn,4,yy', 'Blackmail': 'blau,9,uu', 'Rambo': 'gelb,20,zz'}
```

Comment: Your code assumes that each key in `m_dict` appears in `m_list` 1 time. If `m_list` is something like `['Blackmail','uu']` it throws a KeyError.

Comment: What if I have more elements in the list for example? m_list=['Murder At Koh E Fiza','tt','44','rr','rz','Subedar Joginder Singh','yy','333','33','rr','Blackmail','uu','ee','rr','rr','Rambo','zz','ww','rt','rr']

Answer (score 2):

```
m_dict= {"Murder At Koh E Fiza" : "rot,r", "Subedar Joginder Singh" : "grn,4", "Blackmail" : "blau,9", "Rambo":"gelb,20"}
m_list=['Murder At Koh E Fiza','tt','Subedar Joginder Singh','yy','Blackmail','uu','Rambo','zz']

for i,j in zip(m_list[::2], m_list[1::2]):
    m_dict[i] = '{},{}'.format(m_dict[i], j)
print m_dict

{'Murder At Koh E Fiza': 'rot,r,tt', 'Rambo': 'gelb,20,zz', 'Blackmail': 'blau,9,uu', 'Subedar Joginder Singh': 'grn,4,yy'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple one liner:

`m_dict_2 = {k : m_dict[k] + "," + v for k, v in zip(m_list[::2], m_list[1::2])}`

Comment: This code assumes that each key from `m_dict` also appears in `m_list`. If `m_list` is set to `['Murder At Koh E Fiza','tt']`, then the resulting dict is just `{'Murder At Koh E Fiza': 'rot,r,tt'}`.

Comment: What if I have more elements in the list for example? m_list=['Murder At Koh E Fiza','tt','44','rr','rz','Subedar Joginder Singh','yy','333','33','rr','Blackmail','uu','ee','rr','rr','Rambo','zz','ww','rt','rr']

Answer (score 1):

A **simple** way is to iterate through `m_list` two elements at a time updating the key of `m_dict` on the way.

Using [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

```
m_dict = {"Murder At Koh E Fiza" : "rot,r", 
         "Subedar Joginder Singh" : "grn,4",  
         "Blackmail" : "blau,9",
         "Rambo":"gelb,20"}

m_list = ['Murder At Koh E Fiza','tt','Subedar Joginder Singh','yy','Blackmail','uu','Rambo','zz']

for x, y in zip(*[iter(m_list)]*2):
        m_dict[x] += ',' + y

print(m_dict)

# {'Murder At Koh E Fiza': 'rot,r,tt', 
#  'Subedar Joginder Singh': 'grn,4,yy', 
#  'Blackmail': 'blau,9,uu', 
#  'Rambo': 'gelb,20,zz'}               j
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try range approach with one loop only :

```
m_dict= {"Murder At Koh E Fiza" : "rot,r", "Subedar Joginder Singh" : "grn,4", "Blackmail" : "blau,9", "Rambo":"gelb,20"}

m_list=['Murder At Koh E Fiza','tt','Subedar Joginder Singh','yy','Blackmail','uu','Rambo','zz']

for i in range(0,len(m_list),2):
    data=m_list[i:i+2]
    if data[0] in m_dict:
        m_dict[data[0]]=m_dict[data[0]]+','+data[1]
print(m_dict)
```

output:

```
{'Blackmail': 'blau,9,uu', 'Murder At Koh E Fiza': 'rot,r,tt', 'Rambo': 'gelb,20,zz', 'Subedar Joginder Singh': 'grn,4,yy'}
```